# C# How to loop through multiple XML files and print the string that not found on the XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm new into programming. As for learning purpose, I made simple program that create text file based on file list in directories and the data from the XML file. So, the script is checking on the file list in a folder and search the data in XML file. If the filename match with the string in XML file (`<archetypeName>`), the StreamWriter add line with the name of the string and the attributes (`<position>` and `<rotation>`). My problem is, I don't know how to make if the file name doesn't exist in any XML file, StreamWriter add line that tell the string is not found (fileName + " : data not found"). Here my script to find the data and some XML lines

```
for (int xml = 0; xml < ymapTotalFile; xml++)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(ymapFileList[xml]);
    XmlNodeList nodes = 
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/CMapData/entities/Item");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        itemName = node.SelectSingleNode("archetypeName").InnerText.ToLower();
        for (int i = 0; i < ydrTotalFile; i++)
        {
            XmlElement xmlElement = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("CMapData/entities/Item");

            if (itemName.Equals(modelFileLists[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (itemName.Length > 23)
                {
                    objectPlacementLine.Add(string.Concat(itemName, ", ", "0, ", itemPosition_x, ", ", itemPosition_y, ", ", itemPosition_z, ", ", itemRotation_x, ", ", itemRotation_y, ",itemRotation_z, ", ", itemRotation_w, ", ", "-1", " <--------"));
                    xmlElement.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xmlElement);
                }
                else
                {
                    objectPlacementLine.Add(string.Concat(itemName, ", ", "0, ", itemPosition_x, ", ", itemPosition_y, ", ", itemPosition_z, ", ", itemRotation_x, ", ", itemRotation_y, ",itemRotation_z, ", ", itemRotation_w, ", ", "-1"));
                    xmlElement.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xmlElement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<CMapData>
  <name>cs1_09_long_0</name>
  <parent>cs1_09</parent>
  <entities>
    <Item type="CEntityDef">
      <archetypeName>CS1_09_Build_00</archetypeName>
      <position x="222.32470000" y="6823.11400000" z="17.04211000"/>
      <rotation x="0.00000000" y="0.00000000" z="0.00000000" w="1.00000000"/>
      <scaleXY value="1.00000000"/>
      <scaleZ value="1.00000000"/>
    </Item>
    <Item type="CEntityDef">
      <archetypeName>CS1_09_Ld_03</archetypeName>
      <position x="138.37350000" y="6817.01700000" z="18.73927000"/>
      <rotation x="0.00000000" y="0.00000000" z="0.00000000" w="1.00000000"/>
      <scaleXY value="1.00000000"/>
      <scaleZ value="1.00000000"/>
    </Item>
  </entities>
</CMapData>
```

The output will look like this

```
#IPL generated by Project V tool

inst

1000, 09_build_00, 0, 222.32470000, 6823.11400000, 17.04211000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1
1001, 09_build_01, 0, 1422.05200000, 6546.65700000, 12.06929000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1
1002, 09_build_01_rail1, 0, 1496.97500000, 6563.95100000, 10.19925000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1
1003, 09_build_01_rail2, 0, 1340.35400000, 6576.39300000, 6.08123800, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1

end
```

Comment: You've posted a *lot* of code here - please reduce this to a [mcve]. Your XML file doesn't need to show everything - just enough for us to understand the problem; ditto the code. (For example, do we need the code that finds the `position` and `rotation` attributes? It seems irrelevant to me.) As a side note, I'd urge you to consider using LINQ to XML as a much more pleasant XML API than the old `XmlDocument`-based API.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I'm new in both programming and Stack Overflow. The code and XML has been edited and only show relevant part. And sorry for my bad English

Comment: I strongly suspect you can reduce it further - I'm not trying to get you to do this as a sort of punishment, but a) reducing a problem to a minimal example is a *great* way to solve it yourself; b) it will make it a much better question for Stack Overflow. (Bear in mind that the aim of Stack Overflow isn't to solve your specific question - it's to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. The more obvious it is what higher-level problem you're trying to solve, without being distracted by irrelevant details, the more useful the question is.)